# How to find if Mongodb document has nested object with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As example I want to fetch all user John tasks, which have tags (tags not empty).

```
Post
    .find({user: "John", tags : { contains objId's })
    .exec( function(er, cb) {

       console.log( "Show only posts with tags", cb)


})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If tags is an array:

.find({user: "John",  tags: { $not: { $size: 0} }})

Comment: For array you could also use "tags.0": { $exists: true }

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
.find({user:"John", tags: { $exists:true}})
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. This is the my exact problem. There is property "tags" in document, but it may or may not be empty.

Comment: How tags are declared? Is it array?